# Tests aren't running in a newly generated Unit Test Universal App (VS 2015)

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, windows-10

I am unable to run any unit tests using the built in template project "Unit Test Universal App".

I keep getting this error message :

**Failed to initialize client proxy: could not connect to test process** .

I am on Windows 10 and VS 2015 Ent

**I have tried running VS as an admin I still see the same problem.**

I am using the **Test Explorer**.

Note that i do not see the problem when my target is a mobile emulator. Only when my target is my "Local Machine" is when i see the issue.

*It appears as if the VS Test Engine is trying to create some kind of communication channel (maybe Named Pipes) and it failing either to create it or connect to it*.

Here are a few screenshots of the logs showing VS failing to start the tests :
[image]
[image]

Here's my question on the MSDN forums [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e40ab1ed-b7a9-40d2-91d1-ed56880939b0/tests-arent-running-in-a-newly-generated-unit-test-universal-app-vs-2015?forum=vsunittest)

**Any ideas?**